# ¿Cómo transformar una serie de tiempo diaria a cuatrimestral?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un excel con datos diarios para una variable(evaporación) para 5 lugares  desde 01/01/2000 hasta 31/08/2019 y necesito transformar la información a datos trimestrales, este es la secuencia de comandos que tengo:

```
library(readxl)
evaporacion <- read_excel("directorio", 
                         col_types = c("date", "numeric", "numeric", 
                         "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                         "numeric", "numeric"))
attach(evaporacion)
library(tseries)
data = ts(evaporacion,
          start = c(2000,1,1),
          end = c(2019,31,8),
          frequency = 365)

mydata_quartely = aggregate.ts(data,nfrequency = 4 ,FUN = mean)
```

El problema surge cuando ejecuto la ultima linea, sale un error que dice que no puede transformar datos desde frecuencia 365 a 4.

> Error in aggregate.ts(data, nfrequency = 4, FUN = mean) :    cannot
>   change frequency from 365 to 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes, por que simplemente 365 no es múltiplo de 4. Cada mes, o cuatrimestre tiene distinta cantidad de días, dependiendo del mes e incluso del año (bisiesto). Por lo que siempre deberías pivotear con la fecha exacta para poder hacer cualquier tipo de agregación. Con un `ts` podrías hacer una agregación si por ejemplo ya fuera mensual, a semestres, cuatrimestres, trimestres y bimestres por que 12 es múltiplo de todos estos períodos.

Para lo que intentas hacer, si ya cuentas con un `data.frame` con una `fecha` como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(2019)
data = data.frame(fecha = as.Date.character('2001-01-01') + seq(1, 365*19),
                  valor = runif(365*19)
)
head(data)

       fecha      valor
1 2001-01-02 0.76990155
2 2001-01-03 0.71283973
3 2001-01-04 0.30336020
4 2001-01-05 0.61823636
5 2001-01-06 0.05048374
6 2001-01-07 0.04321880
```

Podemos agrupar por cuatrimestre y aplicar la función `mean()`  gracias a `as.yearqtr()` del paquete `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
data_ym <- aggregate(valor ~ as.yearqtr(fecha), data, mean)
head(data_ym)

  as.yearqtr(fecha)     valor
1           2001 Q1 0.4574261
2           2001 Q2 0.5040360
3           2001 Q3 0.4740474
4           2001 Q4 0.4657588
5           2002 Q1 0.4531709
6           2002 Q2 0.5319238
```

Ya tenemos los datos organizados por cuatrimestres en un `data.frame` común, si lo quieres en una serie de tiempo, podrías hacer:

```
ts(data_ym$valor,
  start = c(2001,1), 
  frequency = 4) -> data_qtr
data_qtr

          Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
2001 0.4574261 0.5040360 0.4740474 0.4657588
2002 0.4531709 0.5319238 0.4647185 0.4793997
2003 0.4992733 0.4806432 0.4991905 0.4941822
2004 0.5240616 0.4513678 0.4847060 0.5245267
2005 0.4921100 0.4942957 0.4783180 0.4951553
2006 0.5084751 0.5294727 0.5060529 0.5213479
2007 0.5462217 0.4669883 0.5292718 0.5154430
2008 0.4981720 0.4818773 0.5111669 0.4664715
2009 0.5860370 0.5278600 0.5397684 0.4739722
2010 0.5407834 0.4338254 0.4667589 0.4804344
2011 0.5250560 0.5327915 0.4529550 0.4845999
2012 0.4736525 0.4880895 0.4823336 0.4906161
2013 0.5238813 0.5257305 0.4842852 0.5433635
2014 0.5033355 0.4742920 0.4947432 0.4833168
2015 0.5499442 0.4833643 0.5602218 0.4580269
2016 0.4910237 0.4637757 0.4503626 0.5100586
2017 0.5212699 0.4880358 0.5297874 0.4874585
2018 0.4925394 0.4871316 0.4607038 0.5632771
2019 0.4765936 0.4946300 0.4536314 0.5211122
```